# Adding Element using append() and set its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, dom

I am using websockets to transmit information from the server to the clients:

```
socket.on('db', function(data) {
    for(i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
        $('#showtable').append(
            $('<tr></tr>').append(
                // many <td>s                   
            )
        );
    } 
});
```

For further use I need the table rows to be numbered so I can select them individually. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: `$('<tr id="' + i + '"></tr>')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, just out of curiosity, why you post your answers as comments?

Comment: @Maximus I normally do that if I don't feel that I have the time to post a complete answer and just want to give a (hopefully) helpful hint. In this case, the OP's next question will probably be 'how do I know which row to select when something happens to an element within the row', in which case an explanation of how to use DOM traversal techniques would be needed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I see, thanks for the clarification)

Answer (score 3):

To set the id as the `i` variable:

```
$('<tr></tr>', { id : i }).append(
    // many <td>s                   
)
```

Although I'm not sure it's necessary because you can easily select a row at a given index with the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, without needing a unique id.

Comment: You don't need open and close tr tag in the selector, just $('<tr/>',{}) is sufficient.